# How to use global css in non cli angular project?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have ASP.NET MVC as server and Angular as client application.

I do not have static index.html but it is index.cshtml. The styles I use are global styles,  not component scoped.

My question is how do I go about working with the scss styles file (bunch of) with angular/webpack and MVC?

Do I have to manually import "global style files" in the app.component file? Do I do the same for vendor css files like bootstrap?

What is the best practice? I'm thinking something as follows:

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import '../styles/myglobalStyles.css'
    import '../styles/boostrap.min.css'
    import '../styles/otherVendors.min.css' 

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent { }
```

Another question is in ANGULAR CLI set up, what is done is to add following in `angular-cli.json` file. What does it do? Does it add styles.css file to the app.component.html during build? (Can you point out to any source/documentations?)

```
],
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: You can add all the css in the `styles.css` and in the `component.scss` to call the `styles` something like this.
`@import "../../../styles";`

And then you call only the classes in the `HTML` and you are fine.

Comment: Please don't change your question like that. Doing so invalidates the current answers. If you have a new question, [ask one](/questions/ask) - **don't edit an existing question with a new question**. Also, take a moment to read [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/332043).

Comment: @Zoe, ok. Is there anyway to get the content of my "new" question?

Comment: if you're referring to the revision I rolled back, there is. If you click on the "edited <x> minutes ago" text, you'll get redirected to [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56165425/revisions). If you click on "source" for any revision, you can [get the plain text version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/887efa29-5723-4fe0-93bb-5921eb8ccf78/view-source).

Comment: got it. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You should use webpack to bundle all scss file and transform all scss file to css then extract it to file call lib.css then include it in Layout.cshtml since it global style for your application. Maybe to improve you can use something third party lib to uglify your css code also to improve performance

Cheers

Comment: do you have webpack config example for what you are talking about?

Comment: Here you are https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js

Comment: What I have is lots of e.g. _button.scss files which gets @imported to the  main.scss file", so how do I make sure that only converted "main.css" files gets appended in the application and also have separate vender.css (e.g. for bootstrap.scss files)? I do not see the wepackconfig you provided is doing that.

Comment: I include everything in lib.scss so it will extract to css file name lib.css

Answer (score 0):

the styles referenced in the component style styleURL metadata, inline in the component template or imported into the component enable CSS encapsulation meaning that they are scoped to the individual component to prevent collisions.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp',
  templateUrl: './comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp.component.css']
})
```

style scope doc https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-scope

To create global style rules that will be applied to any element you can add additional style files, including vendor css to the agular.json which will be bundled by webpack (which is embedded in the cli) and linked to the index.html.

add it to the styles array in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../styles/boostrap.min.css"
],
```

see the docs on workspace configuration for angular cli
https://angular.io/cli#workspace-and-project-configuration

Comment: What I want is 'non cli' solution. I do not have angular.json file.

Comment: then you would need to use webpack or a similar build system to compile your typescript, tree shake, bundle, and chunk your app code for both dev and prod.  To use webpack you would need to add it to your project and configure it.  The whole reason the CLI was created was to reduce the learning curve needed to configure webpack.  CLI has webpack embedded.  But it can be done.  here is a promising looking article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471